# I am trying to configure my Spring boot app to work with Flyway and AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to integrate multiple AWS secrets into my Spring Boot application version 2.6.14 using Flyway for database migration.
However, I am encountering an error message and am unsure of what the problem may be. Can anyone provide guidance on best practices for setting up multiple AWS secrets in a Spring Boot application and troubleshooting tips for resolving errors related to Flyway?

Stack Trace Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ctl.gargoyl3.api.common.aws.secrets.CustomFlywayProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="customFlywayProperties")}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
```

Below is my implementation:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.flyway.my-app-custom")
public class CustomFlywayProperties extends FlywayProperties {
 
  private String awsDbSecret;
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CustomDataSourceProperties.class, CustomFlywayProperties.class})
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DatabaseConfig {  

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public FlywayProperties customFlywayProperties(
          CustomFlywayProperties customFlywayProperties,
          FlywayProperties flywayProperties) {
    boolean hasUsedAwsSecret = false;
    try {
      if (StringUtils.hasText(customFlywayProperties.getAwsDbSecret())) {
        final JSONObject dbCredentials = new JSONObject(customFlywayProperties.getAwsDbSecret());
        flywayProperties.setUser(dbCredentials.getString("username"));
        flywayProperties.setPassword(dbCredentials.getString("password"));

        // Needed since Hikari reads properties directly
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.flyway.user", flywayProperties.getUser());
        properties.setProperty("spring.flyway.password", flywayProperties.getPassword());

        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("aws-custom-flyway-properties", properties));

        hasUsedAwsSecret = true;
      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      log.error("AWS secret property set with error");
    }

    if (!hasUsedAwsSecret) {
      log.info("No AWS flyway credentials secret was configured.");
    }

    return flywayProperties;
  }
}
```